# Problem assembling wings as shown for LEGO Air Race Jet (Technic 42066)

Tags: technic, building

On Page 158 (Step #231) of the assembly instructions for the [Air Race Jet](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42066-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), two red rivet bricks are shown being inserted into a wing.  But the pieces in question will simply fall through the holes in the wing, which appear to be larger than they should be.

Either this is a LEGO error, or else I am missing something obvious.  Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "rivet" bricks are length 2 axles (cross shaped diameter). Beneath the wings, there should be L-shaped 2x4 lift arms. These end in axle holes (also cross shaped) so the axle should fit tight in those, not fall through.
Perhaps you have positioned something erroneously, or you have skipped a step somewhere?

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelVerschaeve! I had positioned the L-shaped lift arms incorrectly.